# How to display label / value on new lines and show another nested label value pair

Tags: html, css, bulma

***This is what I want,***

[image]

***This is what I am getting,***

[image]

***Here's the code, I am using bulma, but I am struggling...***

```
<section class="section">
  <p>Please confirm details below as required and stated before, no jokes</p>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="columns">

      <div class="column is-3 has-text-right has-text-weight-bold">
        Short Label 1:
      </div>
      <div class="column is-2">
        <div class="field">
          <p class="control">
            Short Label 1 Value
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="column is-2 has-text-right has-text-weight-bold">
        Short Label 2:
      </div>
      <div class="column is-2">
        <div class="field">
          <p class="control">
            long value long value long value long value long value long value long value 
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="column is-2 has-text-right has-text-weight-bold">
        Bit Long Label Than Usual 3:
      </div>
      <div class="column is-2">
        <div class="field">
          <p class="control">
            long value long value
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: This is what a table is for

Comment: @Paulie_D nested tables ? :thinking

Comment: anyone please ?

Comment: Do have any CSS defined on those classes?

Answer (score -1):

look like you need to put thats

```
<div class="column ...">
    ...
</div>
```

inside rows

```
 <div class='rows'>
      <div class='row is-full'> column 1 | column 2 </div>
      <div class='row is-full'> column 1 | column 2 </div>
    </div>
```